# opencart jcarousel on latest product

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jcarousel, opencart

Right now I'm learning Opencart, and I'm trying to make my latest product display with jCarousel. I'm using Opencart 1.5.4.

This is what I've already tried, but still failed: http://www.packtpub.com/article/opencart-themes-using-jCarousel-plugin

I'm editing the latest.tpl file step-by-step as in the tutorial, but I'm getting stuck on the eight step.

When I open Firefox and hit refresh nothing happens, no error or message. This is my latest.tpl file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jCarousel/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jCarousel/skins/tango/skin.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#latestcarousel').jcarouseljcarousel();
});

</script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
  <div class="box-content">
    <div id="latestcarousel" class="box-product">
      <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
      <div class="jCarousel-skin-tango">
        <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
        <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
        <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
        <div class="price">
          <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
          <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
        <div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="cart"><input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" /></div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: @bondythegreat 

[14:24:50.703] ReferenceError: reference to undefined property a[h] @ http://localhost/open/catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
[14:24:50.715] ReferenceError: reference to undefined property this.clip[0] @ http://localhost/open/catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jCarousel/js/jquery.jcarousel.js:979
[14:24:50.715] TypeError: this.clip[0] is undefined @ http://localhost/open/catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jCarousel/js/jquery.jcarousel.js:979

Comment: could be `jQuery('#latestcarousel').jcarouseljcarousel();` only `jQuery('#latestcarousel').jcarousel();` ?

Comment: Dear @AlexBall I've already tried that, but nothing seems to happen. error still the same.

I've also tried this jQuery('#latestcarousel').jcarousel(); but still error.

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do with latest.tpl file. It works now.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jCarousel/skins/tango/skin.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#latestcarousel').jcarousel({
scroll: 1,
visible: 3,
auto: 3,
rtl: true,
wrap: 'circular'
});
});

</script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
  <div class="box-content">
    <div class="box-product">
        <ul id="latestcarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
        <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
        <li class="carousel-latest">
            <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
            <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
            <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
            <div class="price">
                <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
            <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
            <?php } ?>
         </div>
         <?php } ?>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for anything.

Comment: You should really add your style in the controller: `$this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/carousel.css');`